# How to get the hash which would be used for a value in a BTreeMap

Tags: hash, rust, btreemap

I'm currently using `BTreeMap` because I need the stable ordering.

Is there a Rust Map structure which would allow me to tentatively add a new key/value to an ordered Map and see what the hash would be?

Currently I have to clone the whole `BTreeMap`, add the key/value, take the hash and drop the clone.  This seems very wasteful.

Comment: I changed the title, mainly to change the vague "map" into the specific BTreeMap. Some map types provide a method to query the hash_builder so the answer wouldn't be the same for HashMap for example.

Comment: If different insertion orders would yield different hashes, then you just need to update the current hash with a new digest. If insertion order shouldn't matter then it's the same thing but you have to make sure your hash update function is *commutative*.

Comment: A problem with this question is it looks like a XY question. The reason why you'd want to see the hash isn't clear and might be based on false premises.

Comment: The question is very confusing, BTreeMap is not hash-based, what hash are you talking about? For a `HashMap`, you can [get a reference to the map's `BuildHasher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.hasher), from that you can create a `Hasher` instance, then `hash` your key using that hasher. Not sure what you'd expect *that* to tell you either tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the hash of the whole tree as returned by its [`Hash::hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html#tymethod.hash) method, then you can see that it is [implemented like this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9f8012e3aa8d5b087100ecd7b109ed3dd2859cca/library/alloc/src/collections/btree/map.rs#L1972):

```
fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
    for elt in self {
        elt.hash(state);
    }
}
```

which can be trivially adapted to insert an element virtually:

```
fn hash_with_extra<H: Hasher>(map: &BTreeMap<i32, i32>, state: &mut H, extra: &(i32, i32)) {
    let mut it = map.iter();
    let mut done = false;
    while let Some (elt) = it.next() {
        if extra.0 == elt.0 {
            extra.hash (state);
            done = true;
            break;
        } else if extra.0 < elt.0 {
            extra.hash (state);
            elt.hash (state);
            done = true;
            break;
        } else {
            elt.hash (state);
        }
    }
    if done {
        while let Some (elt) = it.next() { elt.hash (state); }
    } else {
        extra.hash (state);
    }
}
```

Or using [`itertools::merge`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/fn.merge.html?search=once) and [`std::iter::once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html):

```
fn hash_with_extra<H: Hasher>(map: &BTreeMap<i32, i32>, state: &mut H, extra: &(i32, i32)) {
    for elt in merge (map.iter(), once (extra)) {
        elt.hash (state);
    }
}
```

Comment: @kmdreko thanks, added an example with `merge()`